# Flatpickr second date equals to first selected date

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, calendar, flatpickr

We are using flatPickr with Wordpress plugin in our website. The problem is that plugin is made that dates would be selectable from first day till second day, but we need for user to be able to only select one day. So my idea was to add javascript so when user selects first day, second day would be automatically selected and equal to first selected day. I have added ID elements to both input fields and used this code as example:

[Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56365449/flatpickr-set-date-of-a-second-date-picker-to-the-same-date-of-the-first-one)

But nothing seems to be working

Javascript code example:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    const first_date = document.getElementsByName('_dates[]')[0];
    first_date.id = 'first_date';

    const second_date = document.getElementsByName('_dates[]')[1];
    second_date.id = 'second_date';
});

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    /*selecting datepiker language*/
    flatpickr.localize(flatpickr.l10ns.en);

    /*declaring return datepicker*/
    var FLATPICKER_RITORNO = flatpickr('#second_date', {
        altInput: true,
        altFormat: "j F, Y",
        dateFormat: "d-m-Y",
        disableMobile: "true",
        maxDate: new Date().fp_incr(365),
        defaultDate: "today"
    });

    /*declaring outbound datepicker*/
    $("#first_date").flatpickr({
        altInput: true,
        altFormat: "j F, Y",
        dateFormat: "d-m-Y",
        disableMobile: "true",
        minDate: "today",
        maxDate: new Date().fp_incr(365),
        defaultDate: "today",

        /* setting initial date of return picker to the one selected in 
        outbound*/
        onChange: function (dateStr, dateObj) {
            FLATPICKER_RITORNO.set("minDate", dateObj);
            FLATPICKER_RITORNO.setDate(dateObj);
        }
    });
});
```

[Link to the website](https://dev11.getspace.us/plan.online/)

How it should work:
The date picker is in the main page of the website, when user clicks on "Datos" input field, flatpickr calendar appears. Now he is able to select multiple dates, but he should be able to select only first day and after selecting for example "September 1st" second date would be automatically selected as "September 1st" and the calendar would close.
[Input field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVqCA.png)

Comment: Why are you initializing a flatpicker for _both_ fields to begin with? Why not just for the first field, and then when a value gets picked, you write that into the second field using the change handler?

Comment: But the values are only inserted after the second value is picked, that could be the problem I think? As #first_date is still empty after you select first date

Comment: But that must be due to how you set up the flatpicker to begin with? https://flatpickr.js.org/examples/#human-friendly-dates fills the corresponding input field directly after the dateselection.

Comment: That's correct, but I won't be able to setup flatpicker as I want from the start, as plugin sets it up in its files, so if I will update the plugin, flatpicker will reset. So I think the best way to go is to update second date according to the first one

Comment: But with the JS code you have shown, you are _overwriting_ the flatpicker configuration coming from the plugin, for these fields anyway, no?

Comment: Well I made it to work! Just changed range date to single date, but it still needed two dates, so I just got value from first date and inserted it into second one